# Problems with writing image bytes to socket and then reading them

Tags: c#, android, sockets

I have a java client (android) and c# server. The java client writes to server image's bytes using this piece of code:

```
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

if(startup)
{
    output.writeUTF("#" + message + "#");
    output.flush();
    startup = false;
}
else
if (Integer.parseInt(chatMessagesList.get(chatMessagesList.size() - 1)[2]) == MESSAGE_TYPE_FILE || Integer.parseInt(chatMessagesList.get(chatMessagesList.size() - 1)[2]) == MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE) {
    String imageName = chatMessagesList.get(chatMessagesList.size() - 1)[1];
    imageName = imageName.substring(imageName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(chatMessagesList.get(chatMessagesList.size() - 1)[1]);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    output.writeUTF("#image:" + imageName + "|bytes:" + imageBytes.length + "#"); //METADATA
    output.flush();
    output.write(imageBytes); //IMAGE ITSELF
    output.flush();
} else {
    output.writeUTF("#" + message + "#");
    output.flush();
}
```

And now this is my server code(C#):

```
if(messsage.StartsWith("image:"))
{
    string imageName = messsage.Substring(messsage.IndexOf("image:") + "image:".Length);
    imageName = imageName.Substring(0, imageName.IndexOf("|bytes:"));
    string temp = messsage.Substring(messsage.IndexOf("|bytes:") + "|bytes:".Length);
    int bytesCount = int.Parse(temp);

    byte[] buff = new byte[bytesCount];

    int bytesReceived = client.Receive(buff);

    while(bytesReceived < buff.Length)
    {
        bytesReceived += client.Receive(buff);
        Console.WriteLine("bytes received: " + bytesReceived + "/" + buff.Length);
    }


    //            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buff);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buff))
    {
        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms); //Breaks at this line with the exception* below
        img.Save(clientID + "/files/" + imageName);
        ms.Dispose();
        img.Dispose();
    }
    //           File.WriteAllBytes(clientID + "/files/" + imageName, buff);
}
```

The exception I get:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult = -2147024809
  Message = The parameter is invalid.
  Source = System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       In System.Drawing.Image.FromStream (Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
       In System.Drawing.Image.FromStream (Stream stream)
       In the CloudServer.Program. <> C__DisplayClass4_0. <Main> b__0 () in D: \ Visual Studio Projects \ CloudServer \ CloudServer \ Program.cs: Line 148
       In System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (Object state)
       In System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       In System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       In System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       In System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart ()
  InnerException:
```

I've googled the problem and I understood that it happens because the `MemoryStream` just contains the data of more than 1 image, or data that is not related to the image's bytes.

Comment: Many things could go wrong here, but one error is here: `bytesReceived += client.Receive(buff);` Doing that in a loop you overwrite first bytes in your `buff` every time. You need to do something like `bytesReceived += client.Receive(buff, bytesReceived, buff.Length - bytesReceived, SocketFlags.None);` if you want to use the same buffer.

Comment: I am so dumb! thank you for reminding me that. I though that it will overwrite only the null bytes, but seems like I thought wrong. Post it as an answer so I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not correct:

```
byte[] buff = new byte[bytesCount];
int bytesReceived = client.Receive(buff);
while(bytesReceived < buff.Length)
{
    bytesReceived += client.Receive(buff);
}
```

If you receive image bytes in chunks (very likely) - your `client.Receive(buff)` in while loop will write to `buff` starting at 0, overwriting data you received in previous frame. You want to do it like this instead:

```
while(bytesReceived < buff.Length)
{
    bytesReceived += client.Receive(buff, bytesReceived, buff.Length - bytesReceived, SocketFlags.None);
}
```